# Rolling two dice until a certain sum appears

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two dice (fair) are simultaneously rolled until their sum is equal to either 5 or 7. 
If we know the game has been won by rolling a sum of 5, what is the possibility that it was rolled only two times?

Let $N$ be the random variable of the number of dice tosses and $X$ be the sum with which the game has been finished (so either 5 or 7).I have already computed the following probabilities:

$P[X_N=5]=1/9, P[X_N=7]=1/6$ (The $N$-th toss is a $5$ or $7$).

$P[X_N=5,X_N=7]=5/18$ (The $N$-th toss is either a $5$ or a $7$).

Using the Bayes Theorem I want to obtain

$P[N=2|X=5]=\frac{P[X=5|N=2]P[N=2]}{P[X=5]}$.

Furthermore I have already calculated $P[X=5]=2/5$ and $P[N=2]=5/18\cdot 13/18$.

I dont know how to calculate $P[X=5|N=2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose instead of rolling two dice we draw balls from two urns (which are refilled after each round):

- The *first* urn has 26 red balls and 10 blue balls. Red means "not 5 or 7" and blue means "either 5 or 7".
- The *second* urn has 4 green balls and 6 yellow balls. We draw from it only if the first ball was blue. Green means "5"; yellow means "7".

The game is now:

> Draw balls from the first urn (with replacement) until you get a blue ball; then draw one ball from the second urn.

and the question is

> Given that the ball we drew from the second urn was green, what is the probability that the first urn were used exactly two times?

It should be clear the the second urn is *actually completely irrelevant* to this question, because we only draw from it *after* the number of red/blue draws have already been determined. Your $N$ and $X$ are *independent*, and your calculation of $P(N=2)$ gives you the correct final answer.